# How to run an application at startup as a certain user?

Tags: startup

Is there a way to have an application launch during startup under a certain user account?

For example, I would like to have `a_small_app` run under the user account `bob` (which is in the group `bobsgroup`). Do I add something to `/etc/init.d`?

Note: I don't want the application to start *after a user logs in* but rather when the computer starts.

Comment: Do you want the app to start before login in the login window?

Comment: @Martin: Well, it doesn't really matter... I'm using Apache as an example here. When does it start?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A startup system agnostic method. You can use this in `/etc/rc.local`, a `/etc/init.d/...` script, an Upstart configuration file and probably a systemd configuration too.

```
sudo -u oli /full/path/to/application
```

This command will run as the root user and `sudo` will drop down to the "oli" user. Obviously change the user and the command for your purposes.

I should add that there are at least a dozen ways of doing just this... But in my experience they're all largely identical in effect. Here's an upstart example using its `setuid` stanza:

```
start on (filesystem and stopped udevtrigger)
stop on runlevel [06]

setuid oli
respawn

exec /full/path/to/application
```

Comment: I suggest that the example

Comment: I get `sudo: unknown group: 1004`

Comment: Also, *poke*: Time to update line about upstart.

Comment: @muru I will. But group isn't required. sudo will use the *specified* user's default group.

Comment: Better edit it out, then. That command's been wrong for three years since somebody *improved* it! :D

Comment: Apologies, I incorrectly read that as being all yours.

Comment: +1 for calling it a stanza ❤️

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about older versions of Ubuntu, but recent ones also allow the use of `@reboot` (see e.g. [here in the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Crontab_Lines), scroll down a little or Ctrl+F your way to *@reboot*).

This might be a useful choice for when you want a user to be able to run their own commands at boot time without either having to become root (or have whoever has access to the root account do it for them) or even to have to login. If it works, it works without logging in.

So, as "bob", type `crontab -e`, and then add a new line at the bottom of the file that opens, such as:

```bsh
# bottom of bob's crontab
@reboot /path/to/a_small_app
```

In case it doesn't work, you might want to check your environment variables, especially `PATH`. I usually set `HOME` and `PATH` explicitly atop the crontab. Something like:

```bsh
# top of bob's crontab
HOME=/home/bob
PATH=/home/bob/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

A technique for figuring out why it might not be working:

```bsh
# bottom of bob's crontab
* * * * * /path/to/a_small_app 2>&1 | tee /tmp/a_small_app.log # will run every minute
```

... and then open `/tmp/a_small_app.log` in your favorite editor after 60 seconds to see if there's any useful info in there.

When trying out `@reboot` today to initiate a [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) session within which the command-to-be-run should live, I've stumbled over a stubborn script today, which ended up working with this little trick. Showing it in combination with the above logging thing:

```bsh
@reboot tmux new-session -d -s mysession "bash -c '/path/to/a_small_app 2>&1 | tee /tmp/a_small_app.log'"
```

Comment: If you don't want to mess with bob's crontab, you may alternatively edit the system-wide `/etc/crontab` and add the following line there: `@reboot bob /path/to/a_small_app`. Or put this line into a separate file (say `myapp`) placed in directory `/etc/cron.d`

Comment: awesome ! I came here exactly to see how to start tmux at login, so that last part was the cherry on top. I would add that I passed `-l` to bash to make it a login shell and thus set my `PATH` correctly, without headache of specifying full path to the script

Comment: you should consider adding your answer to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443569/start-tmux-and-execute-a-set-of-commands-on-boot . It works well and feels more intuitive and linux-way than existing answers

Comment: Done. Mulțumesc, Ciprian!

Comment: I found that the `HOME` variable is already set appropriately.
Yet beware that in this context, the command execution does not have a terminal attached, so commands like `watch` do not work.

Comment: Hence "if". I've had missing $HOME, etc. in the wild, esp. in legacy systems.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the first answer doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.10 anymore.

This is how I do it there (put it in /etc/rc.local)

```
su <username> - -c "<command>"
```

Comment: If you need a login shell, the equivalent is `sudo -i -u ...`.